# Trying to improve my retry pinging of TCP port

Tags: c#, winforms, tcp

I'm trying to load two webpage using my cefSharp winform project. The first page sure will display out because it is a local html page. The second page need to do pinging because it is a server website. I need to check whether the server ip and port can be connected first only I redirect to that page. Below is my coding:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-------Initialization------");
        InitializeComponent();

        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        this.Location = new Point(0, 0);

        BrowserSettings browserSettings = new BrowserSettings();
        Console.WriteLine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "html\\index.html");
        browser = new CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "html\\index.html") 
        {// First page.
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        };
        this.Controls.Add(browser);
        browser.BrowserSettings.WebSecurity = CefState.Disabled;
        browser.BrowserSettings.FileAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled;
        browser.BrowserSettings.UniversalAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled;

        while (true)
        {
            pSvr = PingServer(ioIP, int.Parse(ioPort));
            if (pSvr == true)
            {
                label3.Text = "Connected to server. Please wait...";
                tmr.Interval = 15000; 
                tmr.Tick += timerHandler;
                tmr.Start();
                break;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
  }

    public bool PingServer(string _HostIP, int _PortNumber)
    {
        try
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(_HostIP, _PortNumber);
            Console.WriteLine("Server successfully connected...");
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error pinging server...");
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void timerHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tmr.Stop();
            browser.Load("http://" + ioIP + ":" + ioPort + "/page2/?1"); // second page
    }
```

I use a while loop and do a thread.sleep for 5 seconds, to keep retry connect to the server if it failed.

Logically speaking, whether or not I can connect to the second page, I would want the first page to show first, and it will do retry connect to second page in the background. But when I run my code, and when it cannot connect to server, the first page won't come out. Seems like it goes into the while loop and keep retrying to connect to the second page and forget about showing the first page already. Is it the while loop got problem here? Does always showing "Error pinging server..." preventing the first page from displaying? And what do you guys think its the most suitable way for me to do retrying of connecting to server?

Answer (score 0):

> what do you guys think its the most suitable way for me to do retrying of connecting to server?

IMHO, you should not bother with the "ping". All that really matters is whether you can load the page. The server being completely unreachable is only one of many possible reasons it could fail, and even if you successfully "ping" the server, you could still lose the connection after the "ping" but before you load the page, or see a failure for some other reason.

Don't bother trying to detect the server. Just load the page and handle exceptions if they occur.

As for the bigger issue, of the first page not showing up, it's because you are doing way too much in the constructor. The constructor is executed in the UI thread, which is the thread that is responsible for all updates to the visual appearance of your program. Until you return from the constructor, that thread is not able to do anything. So even though you've loaded the page, the control has no way to reflect that on the screen; your constructor is tying up the thread.

The basic solution is "don't do that". There are lots of ways that you could avoid doing that, but in this case I feel like, since you shouldn't be "pinging" the server in the first place, you can solve your problem just by getting rid of that:

```
public Form1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("-------Initialization------");
    InitializeComponent();

    this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    this.Location = new Point(0, 0);

    BrowserSettings browserSettings = new BrowserSettings();
    Console.WriteLine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "html\\index.html");
    browser = new CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "html\\index.html") 
    {// First page.
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
    };
    this.Controls.Add(browser);
    browser.BrowserSettings.WebSecurity = CefState.Disabled;
    browser.BrowserSettings.FileAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled;
    browser.BrowserSettings.UniversalAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled;

    tmr.Interval = 15000; 
    tmr.Tick += timerHandler;
    tmr.Start();
}
```

That will immediately load the first page, wait 15 seconds, and then *try* to load the second page. If the server's there, it will show. If not, you'll get an unhandled exception; best to put a `try`/`catch` there and present the user with some useful information and options (e.g. "failed to connect, retry?").

If you feel like you really must display the `"Connected to server. Please wait..."` message, i.e. perform the ping, then you should do so asynchronously. For example:

```
protected override async void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {
        pSvr = await PingServer(ioIP, int.Parse(ioPort));
        if (pSvr == true)
        {
            label3.Text = "Connected to server. Please wait...";
            tmr.Interval = 15000; 
            tmr.Tick += timerHandler;
            tmr.Start();
            break;
        }
        await Task.Delay(5000);
    }
}

async Task<bool> PingServer(string _HostIP, int _PortNumber)
{
    try
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        await client.ConnectAsync(_HostIP, _PortNumber);
        Console.WriteLine("Server successfully connected...");
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error pinging server...");
        return false;
    }
}
```

The above would replace entirely the loop in your constructor (including starting the timer...note that means that the second page would load not 15 seconds after the first page is loaded, but rather 15 seconds after you successfully detect the server).